# splitting string values of a column in pandas into individual column and converting them to int or float

Tags: python, pandas

i have my dataframe in pandas something like this :

this is df_proto

```
   proto                time
```

8      838,1691461,1690623  May 23 2018 06:31:52 GMT

28     838,1691470,1690632  May 23 2018 06:32:02 GMT

49     838,1691471,1690633  May 23 2018 06:32:12 GMT

70     838,1691474,1690636  May 23 2018 06:32:22 GMT

i want values of proto to split into columns and each value get converted to an int or float.

the code that i tried is this:

df_proto=df3.loc[df3.proto.notnull(),['proto','time']].copy()

df_proto.proto.str.split(',').str[2].astype(int) # here i have to specify which part of proto to convert into int. and also i am not able to add this in the df_proto. and i dont know how many values proto will contain but it is sure that all proto will have same number of value.

please help me with this.

Comment: I think need `df = df3[['time']].join(df3['proto'].str.split(',',expand=True))`

Comment: it worked . but now there are two problems.

first when i am doing df.dtypes, all the columns have type object. i tried converting type of time to string using astype but still under dtypes its type is shown as object. Secondly , how am i supposed to access the values of new  columns created ? their name is 0,1,2. none of  df['0'] or df.0 is working.

Comment: Need `df[0]`, also maybe help [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)